# INSERT Data from one table to another table using OleDB

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I want to insert the `ID` from table `Devices` into table `Log` when clicking "Login" button, but I don't know what to do.

What I want to do is check the device name in table `Devices`, and if there is an existing device name, it will get the `ID` in the table `Devices` to put into table `Log`.

I'm using OleDB and MS Access. I've been searching in Youtube for tutorial but its all SQL.

Here are my tables:

**DEVICES**

```
DEVICE_ItemNumber (AutoNumber; has relationship with LOG_DeviceNumber) 
DEVICE_PCNumber (Short Text)
DEVICE_Room (Short    Text)
DEVICE_Name (Short Text)
```

**LOG**

```
ID (AutoNumber)
LOG_UserID (Short Text)
LOG_Date (Date/Time)
LOG_Time (Date/Time)
LOG_DeviceNumber (Short Text)
LOG_Type (Short Text)
```

**USERS**

```
USER_ID (Short Text; has relationship with LOG_UserID)
USER_Password (Short Text)
USER_GivenName (Short Text)
USER_Surname (Short Text)
USER_Course (Short Text)
USER_YearLevel (Short Text)
USER_Type (Short Text)
USER_Position (Short Text)
```

Here is my code that I've tried using ChatGPT:

```
#region ShowsDashboardForm
public void OpenStudentForm()
{
     //Shows the New Forms
     StudentForm stuForm = new StudentForm();
     stuForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close(); // Close the App is when this Form is Closed
     stuForm.Show();

     StudentForm.GetCurrentUser.currentuser.Text = userIdLoginTextBox.Texts;

     //Close Login form
     this.Hide();
}

public void OpenInstructorForm()
{
     InstructorForm insForm = new InstructorForm();
     insForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
     insForm.Show();

     InstructorForm.GetCurrentUser.currentuser.Text = userIdLoginTextBox.Texts;

     this.Hide();
}

public void OpenSystemAdminForm()
{
     SystemAdminForm sysAdminForm = new SystemAdminForm();
     sysAdminForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
     sysAdminForm.Show();

     SystemAdminForm.GetCurrentUser.currentuser.Text = userIdLoginTextBox.Texts;

     this.Hide();
}
#endregion

#region Login
private void passwordLoginCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     passwordLoginTextBox.PasswordChar = !showPasswordLoginCheckBox.Checked;
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string userIDLogin = userIdLoginTextBox.Texts;
     string passwordLogin = passwordLoginTextBox.Texts;

     // Get the device name
     string deviceName = System.Environment.MachineName;

     // Check the device number in the "DEVICES" table
     int deviceNumber = GetDeviceNumber(deviceName);

     try
     {
         connection.Open();
         cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [USER_ID], [USER_Type] FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = @USER_ID AND USER_Password = @USER_Password", connection);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ID", userIDLogin);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_Password", passwordLogin);

         OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     
         if (reader.Read())
         {
             string userID = reader["USER_ID"].ToString();
             string userType = reader["USER_Type"].ToString();

             switch (userType)
             {
                 case "Student": //Student
                     OpenStudentForm();
                     break;

                 case "Instructor": //Instructor
                     MessageBox.Show("Instructor");
                     OpenInstructorForm();
                     break;

                 case "System Admin": //System Admin
                     MessageBox.Show("System Admin");
                     OpenSystemAdminForm();
                     break;

                 default:
                     MessageBox.Show("Unknown User Type");
                     break;
             }

             if (deviceNumber != -1)
             {
                 deviceNumber++;
                 // Insert the data into the "LOGS" table
                 InsertLoginLog(userID, userType, deviceNumber);
                 MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("This device is not registered.");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Invalid User ID or Password");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
             connection.Close();
     }
}

private int GetDeviceNumber(string deviceName)
{
     using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
     {
         connection.Open();

         // Replace this query with your actual query to check the device number based on the device name
         string query = $"SELECT DEVICE_ItemNumber FROM DEVICES WHERE DEVICE_Name = @DEVICE_ItemNumber";

         using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
         {
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEVICE_ItemNumber", deviceName);

             object result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

             if (result != null)
             {
                 return Convert.ToInt32(result);
             }
         }
     }

     // Return -1 if the device name is not found in the "DEVICES" table
     return -1;
}

public void InsertLoginLog(string userID, string userType, int deviceNumber)
{
     try
     {
         using (OleDbConnection insertConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
         {
             string status = "In";

             insertConnection.Open();
             cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO LOG ([LOG_UserID], [LOG_Date], [LOG_Time], [LOG_DeviceNumber], [LOG_Type]) VALUES ([@LOG_UserID], [@LOG_Date], [@LOG_Time], [@LOG_DeviceNumber], [@LOG_Type])", insertConnection);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOG_UserID", userID);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOG_Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOG_Time", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"));
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOG_DeviceNumber", deviceNumber);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOG_Type", status);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         
     }
}
#endregion
```

This code is working but inserting the `DeviceNumber` into `LOG_DeviceNumber` is incorrect. I already tried the other ID to see if it changes number but it is always 1.

Comment: What Database Management System are you using? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @StefanWuebbe Im using MS Access

Comment: It seems the problem is `object result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` line . It should be `executescalar` because the command is a `select` query.